# Text property not changing when the event is triggered

Tags: c#, text, properties

I'm making a quick quiz game in c# and I'm struggling at making the label (questionLabel) and the buttons (ans1 - ans4) display the specified text, when the play button has been clicked, thank you in advance.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Media;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
         public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    int pointCounter = 0;
    private SoundPlayer _soundPlayer;
    int questionNr = 1;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _soundPlayer = new SoundPlayer("song.wav");
    }

    private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("http://www.amazon.com/Chuck-Seasons-One-Five-Blu-ray/dp/B007AFS0N2");
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _soundPlayer.PlayLooping();
    }


    private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void muteButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (muteButton.Text == "Mute")
        {

            muteButton.Text = "Unmute";
            _soundPlayer.Stop();
        }

        else
        {
            muteButton.Text = "Mute";
            _soundPlayer.PlayLooping();
        }



    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            ans1.Visible = true;
            ans2.Visible = true;
            ans3.Visible = true;
            ans4.Visible = true;
            playButton.Visible = false;

        while (questionNr >= 2)
            {
                if (questionNr == 1)
                {
                    questionLabel.Text = "What is Chuck's full name?";
                    ans1.Text = "fushfus";
                    ans2.Text = "bhfsfs";
                    ans3.Text = "Chuck";
                    ans4.Text = "sfhus";
                }
            }
    }

    private void ans3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (questionLabel.Text == "What is Chuck's full name?")
        {
            pointCounter++;
        }
        else
        {

        }
    }
        public void PointCounter(){
            pointsLabel.Text = pointCounter.ToString();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: questionNr == 1 will always be false in the while questionNr >= 2 loop.

Comment: I have changed the while loop to while (questionNr <2) but now my program crashes

Comment: Why do you need the while loop?

Comment: there will be around 10 questions, I want a while loop that ends the game after questionNr >=10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If button1 is the play button then I guess you got it wrong with the while() loop.

It will never enter the `while(questionNr >= 2)` since questionNr is 1 from when you create the instance.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    int pointCounter = 0;
    private SoundPlayer _soundPlayer;
    int questionNr = 1;  <--

    public Form1() { ... }
}
```

Change:

```
        while (questionNr >= 2)
        {
            if (questionNr == 1)
            {
                questionLabel.Text = "What is Chuck's full name?";
                ans1.Text = "fushfus";
                ans2.Text = "bhfsfs";
                ans3.Text = "Chuck";
                ans4.Text = "sfhus";
            }
        }
```

To:

```
            if (questionNr == 1)
            {
                questionLabel.Text = "What is Chuck's full name?";
                ans1.Text = "fushfus";
                ans2.Text = "bhfsfs";
                ans3.Text = "Chuck";
                ans4.Text = "sfhus";
            }
```